# C++ casting static two-dimensional double array to double**

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, double

I have such matrix in my program:

```
double m[3][4] = 
    {
        {2, 4, 5, 7},
        {4, 5, 1, 12},
        {9, 12, 13, -4}
    };
```

And I'd like to cast it to `double**` type.

I've already tried simple `double** a = (double**)m;`, but it doesn't work (when I try to read any value, I get "Access violation reading location 0x00000000.", which means I'm trying to read from `NULL` adress.

I found almost working solution:

```
double *b = &m[0][0];
double **c = &b;
```

It works when I read field `c[0][any]`
But same NULL adress reading problem occurs, when I try to read value from field `c[1][0]`.

What is the proper way to cast my `double m[3][4]` array to type `double**`?

edit:
You say that's impossible. So I'll change a problem a little bit. How can I pass two-dimensional double array as a parameter to a function? My function has prototype:

```
void calculate(double **matrix, int n); //where matrix size is always n by n+1
```

And it's working fine with dynamically-allocated arrays. I doubt that only way to make it work is allocating new dynamical array and copy original static array one element by another...

Comment: Casting isn't going to make this work. A `double **` requires a pointer to a pointer to a double, and that's not what you have. You can *probably* get by with a `double *` and explicitly passing the array dimensions though.

Comment: An array of arrays and a pointer to a pointer is not the same thing. The layout in memory is not matching so one can not be used for the other.

Comment: Use the technique Vaughn Cato proposed. If it takes a `double**`, you need to give it a `double**` and not a two-dimensional array.

Comment: Your `calculate` function expects a *pointer* to an *array*.  Your problem is that you don't have that.  Your solution is to create that.  Read Vaughn Cato's answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't just cast the array.  You are going to have to create something like this:

```
double m[3][4] = 
    {
        {2, 4, 5, 7},
        {4, 5, 1, 12},
        {9, 12, 13, -4}
    };

double *marray[3] = {m[0],m[1],m[2]};
calculate(marray,3);
```

Or you can use a loop:

```
const size_t n = 3;
double *marray[n];
for (size_t i=0; i!=n; ++i) {
    marray[i] = m[i];
}
calculate(marray,n);
```

Comment: That won't work in my case. Array may have size, for example, 100x100. And I won't write `{m[0],m[1],m[2], ..., m[99]};` in my code :)

Comment: @gogowitczak: In that case, you can use a loop (answer updated).

Comment: It's not that simple. I suppose `array` might have differente sizes that aren't known at compile time, that is, `n` isn't a compile time constant. Hence `marray` must be dynamically allocated. Which might be fine but if you want to avoid dynamic allocation use a template as I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 14):

You can't.

The notation `double**` refers to an array of pointers. You don't have an array of pointers, you have an array of arrays of doubles.

Answer (score 7):

When you write

```
double m[3][4] 
    {
        {2, 4, 5, 7},
        {4, 5, 1, 12},
        {9, 12, 13, -4}
    };
```

The compiler actually creates an array of doubles as if you had written

```
double _m[] = {2, 4, 5, 7, 4, 5, 1, 12, 9, 12, 13, -4};
```

However, thanks to C/C++ type system, the compiler remembers that `m`'s type
is `double [3][4]`. In particular it remembers the sizes 3 and 4.

When you write

```
m[i][j]
```

the compiler replaces it by

```
_m[i * 4 + j];
```

(The `4` comes from the second size in `double [3][4]`.) For instance,
`m[1][2] == 1` and `_m[1 * 4 + 2] == _m[6] == 1` as well.

As others said, a `double**` is a different type which doesn't carry the
sizes with it. To consider `double** a` as a 3 x 4 matrix, `a[0]`, `a[1]` and
`a[2]` must be pointers to `double` (that is, `double*`) pointing to the
first element of the corresponding row. You can achieve this with

```
double* rows[] = { &m[0][0], &m[1][0], &m[2][0] };
double** a = &rows[0];
```

A simple cast doesn't create the variable `rows` above. Let me present other
alternative (but equivalent) ways to define `rows`

```
double* rows[] = { &m[0][0], &m[0][0] + 4, &m[0][0] + 2 * 4};
double* rows[] = { &_m[0], &_m[4], &_m[2 * 4]};
```

As you can see, only the second size (i.e. `4`) is necessary. In general, for
multi-dimensional arrays, all sizes but the first are required. For this
reason a 1-dimensional array

```
double x[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

can be implicitly converted to a `double*`

```
double* y = x;
```

Using this fact we can also write

```
double* rows[] = { _m, _m + 4, _m + 2 * 4};
```

Indeed, `_m` is converted to a `double*` pointing to `m[0]`. Then, in `_m + 4`,
`_m` is is converted to a `double*` pointing to `m[0]` and to this pointer
it's added `4`. Hence, `_m + 4` is a pointer the fourth double following
`_m[0]`, which is `_m[4]` and so on.

So far I have explained why you cannot cast a `double [3][4]` (or any other sizes) to a `double**`. Now, I'shall show, in your particular case, how calculate can be defined.

```
template <int N>
void calculate(double (&m)[N][N+1]) {
   // use m as a double[N][N+1]
}
```

You call

```
calculate(m);
```

and the compiler will deduce the size `N` for you. In general (i.e, when the second dimension is not the `N + 1`) you can write

```
template <int N, int M>
void calculate(double (&m)[N][M]) {
   // use m as a double[N][M]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're always using arrays (no pointers) for initialization, and you are able to avoid the pointer stuff in your calculate function, you might consider the following option, which uses size deduction by templates.

```
template<int m, int n>
void doubleFunc(double (&mat)[m][n])
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (auto j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            std::cout << mat[i][j] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

It worked during my quick test.

```
double m[3][4] = 
{
    {2, 4, 5, 7},
    {4, 5, 1, 12},
    {9, 12, 13, -4}
};

doubleFunc(m);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a 2d array as a function parameter:

`void calculate(double matrix[][y], int n);`

Answer (score 0):

Until variable-length arrays are in the C++ standard, your choices include:

- If your compiler supports variable-length arrays as an extension, you can likely pass them with a function declaration such as `void foo(std::size_t n, double a[][n+1])`. Note that the compiler likely requires `n` to be passed before a parameter declaration that uses `n` or requires some special syntax.
- You can pass a `double *` and do index arithmetic manually in the function: `void foo(std::size_t n, double *a) { … a[row*(n+1) + column] … }`
- You can create a class the implements variable-length arrays by doing the index arithmetic in its accessor functions.
- You can allocate space for `n` pointers to `double`, fill those pointers with pointers to each row of the array, and pass the address of the space.